# Bug in UCF file creation?

Tags: vhdl, pins, spartan

Creating Microbalze using EDK creates a ucf file in the data folder in the same directory , after creating a simple microblaze on spartan 6 using ethernet , and ddr3 IPS i opened UCF file:

```
#  Spartan-6 SP605 Evaluation Platform
Net fpga_0_DIP_Switches_4Bit_GPIO_IO_pin<0> LOC=C18  |  IOSTANDARD=LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_DIP_Switches_4Bit_GPIO_IO_pin<1> LOC=Y6  |  IOSTANDARD=LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_DIP_Switches_4Bit_GPIO_IO_pin<2> LOC=W6  |  IOSTANDARD=LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_DIP_Switches_4Bit_GPIO_IO_pin<3> LOC=E4  |  IOSTANDARD=LVCMOS15;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_tx_clk_pin LOC=L20  |  IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_rx_clk_pin LOC=P20  |  IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_crs_pin LOC=N15  |  IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_dv_pin LOC=T22  |  IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_rx_data_pin<0> LOC=P19  |  IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_rx_data_pin<1> LOC=Y22  |  IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_rx_data_pin<2> LOC=Y21  |  IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_rx_data_pin<3> LOC=W22  |  IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_col_pin LOC=M16  |  IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_rx_er_pin LOC=U20  |  IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_rst_n_pin LOC=J22  |  IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25  |  TIG;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_tx_en_pin LOC=T8  |  IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_tx_data_pin<0> LOC=U10  |  IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_tx_data_pin<1> LOC=T10  |  IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_tx_data_pin<2> LOC=AB8  |  IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_tx_data_pin<3> LOC=AA8  |  IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_MDC_pin LOC=R19  |  IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_PHY_MDIO_pin LOC=V20  |  IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25;
Net fpga_0_Ethernet_MAC_MDINT_pin LOC=J20  |  IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS25  |  TIG;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<0> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<1> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<2> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<3> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<4> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<5> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<6> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<7> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<8> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<9> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<10> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<11> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_addr_pin<12> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_ba_pin<0> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_ba_pin<1> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_ba_pin<2> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_ras_n_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_cas_n_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_we_n_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_cke_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_clk_pin IOSTANDARD = DIFF_SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_clk_n_pin IOSTANDARD = DIFF_SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<0> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<1> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<2> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<3> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<4> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<5> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<6> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<7> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<8> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<9> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<10> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<11> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<12> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<13> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<14> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dq_pin<15> IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dqs_pin IOSTANDARD = DIFF_SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_dqs_n_pin IOSTANDARD = DIFF_SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_udqs_pin IOSTANDARD = DIFF_SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_udqs_n_pin IOSTANDARD = DIFF_SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_udm_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_ldm_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_odt_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_mcbx_dram_ddr3_rst_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_rzq_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_MCB_DDR3_zio_pin IOSTANDARD = SSTL15_II;
Net fpga_0_clk_1_sys_clk_p_pin TNM_NET = sys_clk_pin;
TIMESPEC TS_sys_clk_pin = PERIOD sys_clk_pin 200000 kHz;
Net fpga_0_clk_1_sys_clk_p_pin LOC = K21  |  IOSTANDARD=LVDS_25  |  DIFF_TERM = TRUE;
Net fpga_0_clk_1_sys_clk_n_pin LOC = K22  |  IOSTANDARD=LVDS_25  |  DIFF_TERM = TRUE;
Net fpga_0_rst_1_sys_rst_pin TIG;
Net fpga_0_rst_1_sys_rst_pin LOC = H8  |  IOSTANDARD=LVCMOS15  |  PULLUP  |  TIG;
```

As you can see bitstream is generated , programmed on fpga and also all examples work fine when compiled useing sdk and launched on hardware , but how does everthing works ok when locations of DDR3 are not in ucf file ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically about the microblaze/edk setup, but I do know that when I use coregen for other components (dcms) etc other ucf files are created for those components.  For example if I go to project_dir/ipcore_dir/ I'll see a separate ucf file for each of the coregen modules I've created.  There's likely some other definition files in your project directory (since based on other posts of yours I'm assuming you're using the evaluation kit) that you're not seeing.  If you dig into the directory structure you might find it.  If you're curious try greping for the DDR3 net names that you see in your ucf file.  I'll bet you'll find another ucf that contains their pin locations on board.

Answer (score 0):

Spartan-6 uses a hardwired core block as a DDR interface. I haven't been through the S6 flow but since you don't get a choice about the pin locations I'm not surprised that they simply aren't UCF options.

Different DDR memories have different supply voltages, so it does make sense for the IOSTANDARDs to be specified there.